# Pandas translating column of a dataframe with a lookup dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ISIN': ['A1kT23', '4523', 'B333', '49O33'], 'Name': ['Example A', 'Name Xy', 'Example B', 'Test123'], 'Sector': ['Energy', 'Industrials', 'Utilities', 'Real Estate'],  'Country': ['UK', 'USA', 'Germany', 'China']})
```

I would like to translate the column Sector into German by using the dataframe Sector_EN_DE

```
Sector_EN_DE = pd.DataFrame({'Sector_EN': ['Energy', 'Industrials', 'Utilities', 'Real Estate', 'Materials'], 'Sector_DE': ['Energie', 'Industrie', 'Versorger', 'Immobilien', 'Materialien']})
```

so that I get as result the dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ISIN': ['A1kT23', '4523', 'B333', '49O33'], 'Name': ['Example A', 'Name Xy', 'Example B', 'Test123'], 'Sector': ['Energie', 'Industrie', 'Versorger', 'Immobilien'],  'Country': ['UK', 'USA', 'Germany', 'China']})
```

What would be the apropriate code line?

Comment: You need to merge two dataframes https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way via `map()`:

```
df['Sector']=df['Sector'].map(dict(Sector_EN_DE[['Sector_EN', 'Sector_DE']].values))
```

OR

via `replace()`:

```
df['Sector']=df['Sector'].replace(dict(Sector_EN_DE[['Sector_EN', 'Sector_DE']].values))
```

Answer (score 0):

This line will do the merge and DataFrame cleanup:

```py
df.merge(Sector_EN_DE, left_on='Sector', right_on='Sector_EN').drop(['Sector', 'Sector_EN'], axis=1).rename(columns={'Sector_DE': 'Sector'})
```

Explanation:

- The `merge` function do the join between both DataFrames.
- The `drop` function drops the English version of `Sector`, with `axis=1` because you're dropping columns (you can also use that function to drop rows).
- The `rename` function renames the `Sector_DE` column.